# Multiple equations in one boolean statement

Tags: oop, boolean, boolean-expression

I think this is a really general programming question, since boolean syntax is more or less the same in a lot of common languages.

But still my question is for php and javascript mainly.

Suppose I want to write an if statement which returns true if a variable is equal to 2,3, or 5.
And this variable has a very long name, so like this:

```
if((An_Object_With_A_Long_Name.Has_Also_An_Array[With_An_Index_Too]==2) 
   || (An_Object_With_A_Long_Name.Has_Also_An_Array[With_An_Index_Too]==3) 
   ||(An_Object_With_A_Long_Name.Has_Also_An_Array[With_An_Index_Too]==5))
{
  return true;
}
```

and I really want my code look shorter, it is less depressing to read it months after :)

so can I simplify this into something like

```
if(An_Object_With_A_Long_Name.Has_Also_An_Array[With_An_Index_Too]==2||3||5)
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Create a collection (list,array,etc.) of your valid values, and then do something like `if validValues.Contains(An_Object_With_A_Long_Name.Has_Also_An_Array[With_An_Index_Too])) { return true; }`

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I'm asking for this is I'm trying to stay away from extra memory allocation, so I would really appreciate it if there is a way for this without extra variables.

Comment: Extra memory allocation?  How many valid values are there?  A collection of several hundred million would probably consume 1 GB of memory.

Comment: You need to worry about clean code first.  If you encounter a memory issue, then debug and test to determine what needs to be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Cheater way out: For that if statement, assign An_Object_With_A_Long_Name to Object i. (If you plan to have to compare this variable several times, assign Object i the pointer of An_Object_With_A_Long_Name.

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to learn (if there are any) ways to simplify boolean statements. So no cheaters!! :)

Comment: mbeckish's solution seems much more appropriate and less cheater-ish :)